# Using CSS Sprites with Drupal

Tags: 7, theming

I ran a Page Speed review of my website and got a suggestion that I should combine some images on my site into a single image using CSS sprites. I assume it is the mistake of the person who coded the theme, and I cannot recode it due to lack of knowledge. Is there any easier way of achieving this in Drupal? What I am looking for is solutions like [this](https://drupal.org/project/sprites) and [this](https://drupal.org/project/sprite) that would make the process easy for Drupal 7.

Comment: I am looking for specific instructions on how to achieve this in Drupal (any module, library or anything similar).

Comment: I do not think there will be module for this.Your themer needs to create a sprite of images and then you have to do css changes to give appropriate positions to images.

Comment: @Webmaster Drupal won't help with combining your images and generating CSS. There are tools like [sprite.me](http://spriteme.org/) that can help though

Comment: I am asking if there is anything available like this[https://drupal.org/project/sprites] and this[https://drupal.org/project/sprite] that eases the process for drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal's primary role is a CMS. For development tooling, it's probably more effective and more efficient if you build sprites without the use of Drupal. Drupal itself already has a very large memory footprint.

### How to produce CSS sprites (2013/2014 Edition)

With today's rapid growth in development tooling and technology, here are just some ways of which one can produce sprites for your theme today:

- **Manually** Manually edit them in photoshop and place them accordingly in the same file and write css for it. If this isn't clear to you. There's a plethora of information on how to do this: [here](http://alistapart.com/article/sprites), [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp), [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/31/transparent-css-sprites/), and yes there's plenty of more articles out there. Just search for "css sprites" in your favorite search engine.
- **Use Compass** [Compass](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/), a Ruby Gem, allows one to automatically generate sprites. It's very well used and integrated in some themes today. For example, [Zurb Foundation](https://drupal.org/project/zurb-foundation).
- **Grunt Spritesmith** If you're familiar with using Grunt and have node already setup on your local machine [Spritesmith](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-spritesmith) is a viable option. Spritesmith allows you to create sprites within a folder for use of your theme.
- **CSS Sprite Generator** - I quickly googled 'css sprite generator' and found [this particular tool](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/). Not sure if it's helpful but it seems as to allow you to build sprites online via upload.

Again, IMHO i'm pretty skeptical and think that outdated Drupal 5 [sprite module](https://drupal.org/project/sprites) will improve your front performance when you have to load one more module.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty alternative to CSS sprites is embedded images in CSS. https://drupal.org/project/css_emimage is the module to use. Be sure to use it along with [AdvAgg](https://drupal.org/project/advagg)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that module either because that module forces all your images to be base64'd and baked into your css. Good luck waiting for your pages to paint on mobile browsers: http://www.mobify.com/blog/data-uris-are-slow-on-mobile/